# Custom Spring Security Authentication provider not even being called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a requirement to authorize users from a 3rd party app. Basically it's a REST api call,  but that's not the problem.  Every time I navigate to a page,  I get automatically re-directed to the error page, with no explanation at all.  There is nothing in the logs, even with my logging:  logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG  and my root level at WARN

My Security Configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConfigurationProperties("security")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  ELPAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    elpLogger.debug("****************Configuring HttpSecurity");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

}
```

And my Authentication Provider:

```
@Component
public class ELPAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    logger.debug("In Authenticate");
    final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    final UserBean principal = new UserBean("admin", "password", grantedAuths);
    final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, "password", grantedAuths);
    return auth;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

To me,  this looks like it should authenticate anything. But everything but my HelloWorldController  ("/hello")  I get thrown to my error page with no explanation. My log looks like this:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated]
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:7080/ to session
o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
c.e.web.controllers.ELPErrorController   : ************************  Error handler
```

So I don't know why my authentication provider is not even being called,  and secondly,  I have NO idea why an exception is being thrown.  (Or why am I being re-directed to the error page and not the not-authorized page)

Any Ideas?

**EDIT**
I removed the @Component annotation from the AuthenticationProvider and declared it a bean in my main Application.java  Autowired it into the SecurityConfiguration.  I made the changes in the example above.  Exact same problem.  No Change.

Comment: please (1.) also ensure `logging.level.<package.of.elpauthenticationprovider>=debug` and (2.) is it a component (auto scan?) or a bean? (i know/understand it is quite the same, but could be conflicting..when used together (no warnings??))

Comment: @xerx593  No change.  the log level was debug.  But I did have both the component annotation,  and declared it a Bean.  I removed the component annotation and put the Bean method in the Application.java   I adjusted the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: In addition to @fast-reflexes answer below, make sure you don't call `http.authorizeRequests()` twice. The 2nd call overwrites the first. You can chain rules together, as in: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello/**").permitAll()..anyRequest().authenticated()`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `authenticate` method in the `AuthenticationProvider` interface takes an authentication as argument, we can rest assured that some kind of initial authentication has to be in place, to give the provider something to work on. The following excerpts are given in Kotlin.

Even with a standard setup with basic authentication

```
@Configuration
class SecurityAssets {

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder =
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()

} 

@EnableWebSecurity
class Config(val encoder: PasswordEncoder): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()         
               .withUser("user")
               .password(encoder.encode("password"))
               .roles("USER")
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
    } 
}
```

the above will not trigger an authentication to take place. To make this happen, we need to add some method for Spring to create the initial authentication which is then authenticated by the configured provider:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class Config(val encoder: PasswordEncoder): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    ...

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
    } 
}
```

Now it works!

Similarly in your case, something like this will work:

```
class CustomAuthenticationProvider : AuthenticationProvider {

    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Authentication {
        println("In Authenticate")
        val grantedAuths: MutableList<GrantedAuthority> = ArrayList()
        grantedAuths.add(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
        val principal = AuthenticatedPrincipal { "Name" }
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, "password", grantedAuths)
    }

    override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        println("In supports")
        return true
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
class Config(val encoder: PasswordEncoder): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(CustomAuthenticationProvider())
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
    } 
}
```

How you make the custom provider available to the configurer is not important, you can use a bean or simply instantiate it in place if you want it.

If you need some different main authentication method, you can change `httpBasic` to something else. If you need to customize the actual method of authentication (e.g. look for some custom headers or something else for which a filter does not already exists), then you should implement a custom filter which is added to the security filter chain and which then delegates to your provider.

The filters in the security filter chain are what actually processes a request and simply adding a security provider doesn't add a new filter, which, in this case, `httpBasic` does.